# MSSQL select only last record values by distinct column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS Sql Server (14.0)

I have a table that was created by a non-forward-thinking developer:

```
create table product_history
(
    product_code varchar(10),
    product_description varchar(100),
    price numeric(10,3)
);
```

He didn't create an Index, or an Identity column.

And people have been adding records to the table:

```
insert into product_history values ('a','apples', 3);
insert into product_history values ('b','banana', 6);
insert into product_history values ('a','apple', 6);
```

Now I want to select only distinct records based on when the order they were inserted (i.e. rowno ascending)

so the result set I'd like is:

> 'b', 'banana', 6
>
> 'a', 'apple', 6

How do I create a query that will select all the column values from only the last record by distinct product_code?

Comment: "rowno ascending..." -- Your table doesn't have a row number... The question doesn't make too much sense. Voting to close.

Comment: @TheImpaler MSSQL has an inbuilt ROW_NUMBER function - I thought that could be used here

Comment: If you are talking about the `ROW_NUMBER()` *window function* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) then it does require you to specify an `ORDER BY` clause. Otherwise it doesn't make sense. Or are you talking about a different function?

Comment: I've added an identity column to order-by as suggested by @gordon, I know the generated Ids won't *strictly* follow insertion order, but it will give me a basis to track from here onwards and I can use the query he suggested to pick the "non-strictly" most recently added rows.  I've noted your comment about a datetime stamp being more reliable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a *last* record.  The table should be created as:

```
create table product_history (
    product_history_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    product_code varchar(10),
    product_description varchar(100),
    price numeric(10,3)
);
```

Then you could simply do:

```
select ph.*
from product_history ph
where ph.product_history_id = (select max(ph2.product_history_id)
                               from product_history ph2
                               where ph2.product_code = ph.product_code
                              );
```

You could do essentially the same thing if there where a `created_at` column, such as:

```
created_at datetime default getdate()
```

There is not really much that you can do to address this.  I would suggest starting over and keeping the history from today.  That may seem extreme, but in a year or two, you'll have history.

If you have snapshots or backups of the database, you can go back and attempt to reconstruct the history using a correct data model.  Or might might be able to use the transaction log, assuming prices were changed using `update`s.

If you know that prices are always increasing (or always decreasing), you could use that information to get the most recent price.

Comment: Even `product_history_id` may not represent ascending order in case of cycles. or backup/restore operations. It's safer to use a date/time column.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no id or timestamp value present, it's going to be hard to figure out which one was the last entry. A possible solution would be to create a copy of the table with additional columns for id and timestamp and create a trigger against the old table to update the new table whenever there's an insert. Here's the reference on how to create a trigger:

```
-- SQL Server Syntax  
-- Trigger on an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement to a 
-- table (DML Trigger on memory-optimized tables)  
  
CREATE [ OR ALTER ] TRIGGER [ schema_name . ]trigger_name   
ON { table }   
[ WITH <dml_trigger_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
{ FOR | AFTER }   
{ [ INSERT ] [ , ] [ UPDATE ] [ , ] [ DELETE ] }   
AS { sql_statement  [ ; ] [ ,...n ] }  
  
<dml_trigger_option> ::=  
    [ NATIVE_COMPILATION ]  
    [ SCHEMABINDING ]  
    [ EXECUTE AS Clause ]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

You would then write your query against this new table.